# updating column not working in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, random

I want to insert random integers between 9000 and 7500 into a column in PostgreSQL. So I used:

```
update public.table
set column_name = floor(random() * 9000 + 7500)::int;
```

But it is not updating the column. How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update public.table
set column_name = floor(random() * 9000 + 7500)::int;
```

This condition `floor(random() * 9000 + 7500)::int` gets evaluated only once. What you want is to either

- Create a query with a `uniqueid|randomid` and join that to `public.table` for the update.
- Create a new table with those random ids.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE mytable AS
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
    floor(random()*(9000-2500)) + 2500 AS rand
  FROM generate_series(1,1000);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Instead of joining I created the table and the inserted the rand column into my public.table(column_name) .

Comment: I wish there was a way to call `random()` so that it will be evaluated once per row.